# getting error while droping user from redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

In AWS redshift I am using superuser to drop the user and also removed all the dependencies but still getting the following error.

No row in the coming after running scripts in the below URL.
https://github.com/gdex-lab/redshift-tools/blob/master/scripts/drop_redshift_user.py

SQL Error [500310] [2BP01]: Amazon Invalid operation: user "xxxxx" cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it
Details:
1 object in database dev;

Could Pls help me in this regard?

Comment: Was this eventually solved? I'm getting a similar error after following the directions in the Github document.

Comment: still not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used this code provided by awslabs to identify all objects owned by a user?  https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/AdminViews/v_find_dropuser_objs.sql

It is a common challenge to find everything that a user owns.

Comment: Yes I did check there is no row coming in the result.

Comment: Does the user have any active session?  Do they own any stored procedures or UDFs?

Comment: neither connection nor any proc.

Comment: Is the user a superuser?  (I'm stretching now)  Is it possible that some other user/session has assume this users permissions?  (set session authorization <user>)    I can think of more "possibilities" but if may be worth a ticket to support.

Comment: it's a simple user not showing any user session so assume no connection for the user.

Comment: I'll stop the guessing game.  It may be time to get AWS support involved as they can look at what is going on from the OS level.  Other things to try (if you haven't already): Reboot the cluster to see if some temporal issue is the cause.  Hunt through the system tables for this users uid - there has been a lot of changes in the past couple of years and the awslabs code may not have kept up.